# HTML Links won't open on iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ipod

I have an UIWebView containing links. These links should open in another view inside my app, except links containing "mailto". To achieve this, I'm using the following code inside the UIWebViews delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) 
    {
        NSRange mailPos = [[[request URL] absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"mailto:"];
        if (mailPos.location == NSNotFound)
        {
            self.parent.browserView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self.parent.setupViewC presentModalViewController:self.parent.browserView animated:TRUE];
            [self.parent.browserView.wvMainView loadRequest:request];
        }   
        else [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

This works fine in the simulator and on the iPhone - but it doesn't work at all on iPods. Clicking on a link just doesn't do anything on an iPod Touch.

Calling

```
[self.parent.browserView.wvMainView loadRequest:request];
```

after a click on an UIButton does work however.
So is there any way to make the links inside the UIWebView work on an iPod too?

Comment: Does the iPod have a mail account set up in the Mail app? I'm not sure this would prevent you from opening a mailto: url using the openURL method, but it's a longshot.

Comment: was thinking same thing. +1 for Jasarien

Comment: I'm not sure about the mail account setup, but the normal http links also don't work on the iPod. On my test iPhone, without any mail accounts configured, both the mail and the standard http links open without any problems. I've tested it on 4 iPhones and 2 iPods so far - both iPods won't open any link from my UIWebView, all iPhones open all the links.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
in main thread

in the else case try the following

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:.....];